# Join table by two columns from same table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following table

```
+---------------------------------------+
|                 Company               |
+------+-------+--------------+---------+
|  id  |user_id|company_parent|   name  |
+------+-------+--------------+---------+
| COIE |   1   |     null     | company |
+------+-------+--------------+---------+
| AGCY |   1   |     COIE     |  agency |
+------+-------+--------------+---------+
| COIE |   2   |     null     | company |
+------+-------+--------------+---------+
```

Basically each company has a set of agencies, and each agency has a parent company (the value of the company_parent column in case its a mother company is null), both the id and user_id are primary keys, but in my mapping i only announced the id as the @id (because i added the user_id as a primary key later, and to add new class with a composite key is really painful)

So i want to create a sub-list for each company to get its related agencies, using both the user_id column and the company_parent column.
here is my current mapping:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_parent")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Company parentCompany;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCompany")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private List<Company> agencies;
```

The problem with this mapping that it does not take the user_id into consideration.
I tried this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_parent"), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
})
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Company parentCompany;
```

But i get: `wrong number of column. should be 1`
How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this with annotations might be to leverage `@Filter` and `@FilterDef` which are Hibernate-specific to apply a filter based on state on the agencies list.

A portable way would be to simply make the `List<Country> agencies` a transient list that your business logic populates after fetching a `Company` entity. Your fetch could use both the desired `user_id` and `company_parent` restrictions without having to worry with mappings.

With the field being transient and accessing it as if it were a property mapped by hibernate, you could easily adopt the composite key changes at a later point in development and simply remove the additional fetch in favor of a mapping change.  From the business code, it should then behave as it did using the transient approach.